# Key is defined but it warns "Each child in a list should have a unique key prop"

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

although I defined a key for SearchDropDownItem it shows a warning

**component DropDown**

```
filteredItems.length > 0 ? (
  filteredItems.map(item => {
    return (
      <SearchDropDownItem
        item={item}
        buttonTitle={{ buttonJoin: content.buttonJoin }}
        onItemSelect={onItemSelect}
      />
    );
  })
) : (
  <SearchDropDownItem emptyList={content.noCommunityFound} />
)
```

**searchDropDownItem component :**

```
const SearchDropDownItem = ({
  item = {   },
  onItemSelect,
  buttonTitle = "",
  emptyList
}) => {
  return (
    <DropdownItem key={item.id || 1}>
      {!emptyList ? (
        <Box>
          <Span>{item.name} </Span>
          <JoinButton
            item={item}
            index={item.id}
            onSuccess={onItemSelect}
            content={buttonTitle}
          />
        </Box>
      ) : (
        <Box>
          <Span>{item.emptyList}</Span>
        </Box>
      )}
    </DropdownItem>
  );
};
```

**Warning**: *Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `SearchBox`. 
    in SearchDropDownItem (at SearchBox/index.jsx:52)*

Comment: The key needs to be in DropDown, where the map is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should place the key where you use the `SearchDropdownItem`, so in the loop.

```
filteredItems.length > 0 ? (
  filteredItems.map(item => {
    return (
      <SearchDropDownItem
        key={item.id} // <-- This is where it has to be
        item={item}
        buttonTitle={{ buttonJoin: content.buttonJoin }}
        onItemSelect={onItemSelect}
      />
    );
  })
) : (
  <SearchDropDownItem emptyList={content.noCommunityFound} />
)
```

Docs on keys in React: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Answer (score 0):

I got the same warning message:
`Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.`

However, my problem and solution were a bit different than the accepted answer. I thought adding my solution to this question might help someone.

I am using a 3rd party component, which has a unique key. However, when I used a loop to dynamically generate several instances of the component, I got the warning message above.

The warning disappeared after I **added a key prop** to the component. This key is NOT part of the props for the component.

```js
let filterJSX = [];
let i = 0; 
for (let [key1, value1] of Object.entries(state.filterListNew)) { 
    i++; 
    filterJSX.push(
        <MultiSelectModalField
            key={i.toString()} // I added this one

            items={optionList}
            uniqueKey="value"
            displayKey="name"
            // more properties here... 
        />
    );
}
```